# udl connection string works but my ASP.Net file throws an exception when connecting

Tags: asp.net, mysql, string, connection

I have recently taken the plunge from classic ASP to ASP.Net and I am having trouble connecting to my test database.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and MySQL 5.6 and i am following [this](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/mysql/first-access/) tutorial.

I have created a UDL file in which the test connection succeeded, and in my application, i have added the following to the connection string (which is the same string i used in the UDL to connect):

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="MyConn" connectionString="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver};Database=Zen;Server=localhost;UID=root;pwd=*****;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

which is the same connection string i used while creating the UDL file.

My application throws the following exception when i run it:

An error occured: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

I don't know if this will help, but my cs code is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data;

namespace Zen
    {
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                try
                {
                    using(OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using(OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT name FROM test_users", connection))
                    using(OdbcDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while(dr.Read())
                            Response.Write(dr["name"].ToString() + "<br />");
                        dr.Close();
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("An error occured: " + ex.Message);
            }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I fixed the issue by installing the 32 bit MySQL ODBC drivers.